# filter data while fetching symfony api in react

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, symfony

I'm doing this page in react where I render the result of an api that return the list of a movies from db , I wanna filter them for genre using dropdown, where dropdown items are fetched from genre table.
So when a click on a genre in dropdown I want to upload the page with the list of movies filtered.
I show my code:
Api:

```
#[Route('/api/movies/genre/{genre}')]
    public function listFiltered(Connection $db, $genre): Response
    {
        $query = $db->createQueryBuilder()
            ->select("m.*")
            ->from("movies", "m")
            ->innerJoin('m', 'movies_genres', 'mg', 'mg.movie_id = m.id')
            ->where('mg.genre_id = :genre')
            ->setParameter('genre', $genre)
            ->setMaxResults(50)
            ->executeQuery()
            ->fetchAllAssociative();
        dd($query);
        return $this->json([
            "filtered" => $query
        ]);
    }
```

my react page:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Button, Rating, Spinner, Dropdown } from 'flowbite-react';

const Index = props => {
  const [movies, setMovies] = useState([]);
  const [filtered, setFiltered] = useState([]);
  const [genres, setGenres] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  const fetchMovies = () => {
    setLoading(true);

    return fetch('/api/movies')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        setMovies(data.movies);
        setLoading(false);
      });
  }

  /*const fetchFilteredMovies = async (e) => {
    const genre = e
    const response = await fetch(`api/movies/genre/${genre}`);
    const data = await response.json();
    setFiltered(data.filtered);
    <MovieList>
      {filtered.map((item, key) => (
        <MovieItem key={key} {...item} />
      ))}
    </MovieList>;
  }*/

  const fetchGenres = () => {
    return fetch('api/genres')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        setGenres(data.genres);
      })
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchMovies();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchGenres();
  }, []);
  return (
    <Layout>
      <Heading />
      <Dropdown
        label="Genres"
        dismissOnClick={false}
      >
        {genres.map((item, key) => (
          <DropdownItem key={key} {...item}
            {...onclick = async function fetchFilteredMovies() {
              const response = await fetch(`api/movies/genre/${props.id}`);
              const data = await response.json();
              setFiltered(data.filtered);
              <MovieList>
                {filtered.map((item, key) => (
                  <MovieItem key={key} {...item} />
                ))}
              </MovieList>;
            }}
          />
        ))}
      </Dropdown>
      <br></br>
      <MovieList loading={loading}>
        {movies.map((item, key) => (
          <MovieItem key={key} {...item} />
        ))}
      </MovieList>
    </Layout>
  )
};

const DropdownItem = props => {
  return (
    <Dropdown.Item
    >
      {props.id}
    </Dropdown.Item>
  );
};

const Layout = props => {
  return (
    <section className="bg-white dark:bg-gray-900">
      <div className="py-8 px-4 mx-auto max-w-screen-xl lg:py-16 lg:px-6">
        {props.children}
      </div>
    </section>
  );
};

const Heading = props => {
  return (
    <div className="mx-auto max-w-screen-sm text-center mb-8 lg:mb-16">
      <h1 className="mb-4 text-4xl tracking-tight font-extrabold text-gray-900 dark:text-white">
        Movie Collection
      </h1>

      <p className="font-light text-gray-500 lg:mb-16 sm:text-xl dark:text-gray-400">
        Explore the whole collection of movies
      </p>
    </div>
  );
};

const MovieList = props => {
  if (props.loading) {
    return (
      <div className="text-center">
        <Spinner size="xl" />
      </div>
    );
  }

  return (
    <div className="grid gap-4 md:gap-y-8 xl:grid-cols-6 lg:grid-cols-4 md:grid-cols-3">
      {props.children}
    </div>
  );
};

const MovieItem = props => {
  return (

    <div className="flex flex-col w-full h-full rounded-lg shadow-md lg:max-w-sm">
      <div className="grow">
        <img
          className="object-cover w-full h-60 md:h-80"
          src={props.image}
          alt={props.title}
          loading="lazy"
        />
      </div>

      <div className="grow flex flex-col h-full p-3">
        <div className="grow mb-3 last:mb-0">
          {props.year || props.rating
            ? <div className="flex justify-between align-middle text-gray-900 text-xs font-medium mb-2">
              <span>{props.year}</span>

              {props.rating
                ? <Rating>
                  <Rating.Star />

                  <span className="ml-0.5">
                    {props.rating}
                  </span>
                </Rating>
                : null
              }
            </div>
            : null
          }

          <h3 className="text-gray-900 text-lg leading-tight font-semibold mb-1">
            {props.title}
          </h3>

          <p className="text-gray-600 text-sm leading-normal mb-4 last:mb-0">
            {props.plot.substr(0, 80)}...
          </p>
        </div>

        {props.wikipedia_url
          ? <Button
            color="light"
            size="xs"
            className="w-full"
            onClick={() => window.open(props.wikipedia_url, '_blank')}
          >
            More
          </Button>
          : null
        }
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Index;
```

How can I do this?